# How to shutdown Ubuntu with exec PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

I really need to shut down ubuntu with PHP exec. But I probably have some problem with permission.

```
echo exec('whoami')
```

return 'nobody';

So I put in console

```
adduser nobody admin
```

and tried

```
exec("shutdown -h now");
```

But It doesn't work ;(

Comment: Giving the user PHP runs as root rights is **highly dangerous**.

Comment: This should be in the running for, "Worst idea, ... EVER!"

Comment: I know, I know, but can U help me with my example ;( ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Giving the user PHP runs as root rights is **highly dangerous**. This is not a good idea at all, because you open up your whole server if a  vulnerability in a PHP script gets exploited. On a production server, this is absolutely not acceptable.

The only way to do this securely that I know of is having a cron job run a shell script as root every minute or so. The shell script tests for the presence of a file like `shutdown_now.txt`. If the file exists, the script starts the shutdown procedure. The PHP script creates the shutdown file if so instructed.

I'm not well versed enough in shell scripting to provide an example, but I'm sure somebody can if necessary.

Comment: I know about dangerous, but I i would like do this simple as possible.

Comment: Convenience over security. Nice.

Comment: @Domiik I'm not a Linux expert, but the sysadmin group should probably be called `root` instead of `admin`. Alternatively, Ubuntu seems to have a command `users-admin`. Then there's `/etc/group` that controls the user groups. As said, it's horribly dangerous and not a good idea even for a private home server.

Comment: @Domiik - the group you are looking for is probably named `wheel`, but I don't think you want to give an anonymous system user access to that.

Answer (score 10):

Actually Pekka gave you a good advice. In your php file create a file that will force rebooting, something simple like

```
  $file = fopen('.reboot-server',"w");
  fwrite($file, 'reboot');
  close($file);
```

Make a bash script that will check for that file

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/www/html/.reboot-server ]; then
  rm -f /var/www/html/.reboot-server
if [ -f /var/www/html/.reboot-server ]; then
   echo "Can't remove file .reboot-server"
else
  /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
fi
```

And add it under cronjob

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/scripts/reboot.sh
```

Comment: An old answer but a good one. And I think we need to have write permissions for the folder where the file is being created right?

Comment: I ain't an expert with bash but shouldn't rm need sudo or authentication to run?

Comment: If your crontab is running with root privileges, then your cronjob should be `*/1 * * * * /home/scripts/reboot.sh` not `*/1 * * * * root /home/scripts/reboot.sh` otherwise it will not be executed.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is illustrative *only*. Do *not* actually do this.

- Make a copy of `/sbin/shutdown` (as root) to a place where the PHP user can access it.
- Set the SUID bit of the copy, so that it can run as root. `chmod 4755 /copy/of/shutdown`

When PHP executes the copy of shutdown, `shutdown` will run with root privileges. This eliminates the cron job and the possibility that a stale 'shutdown_now.txt' would cause the system to halt again shortly after being powered up.

Again, the wholesale use of the setuid bit is **dangerous**. Any time you use it, think **carefully** about what the program might be able to do if abused. In this case, a hole in your app could cause an attacker to remotely halt the system. But, the attacker could do that no matter what method you use to talk to `shutdown`. It's up to you if that is an acceptable risk.

Additionally, if you are going to do this, do **not** run PHP as an anonymous system user, you really want suexec. Just make *sure* there's no way to pass anything arbitrary to the command you send. Don't let someone get a `&& do_evil_deed` on the end of, or beginning of it.

A *much* safer way to do this would be through the use of any one of the available SSH classes for PHP, connecting as a user jailed in a chroot, with sudo rights *only* to the shutdown program. Or, basically, *any* time PHP needs to do something to the OS, imagine the smallest surface you can think of in order to do it, then try to make it even smaller.

Comment: +1 this is far from entirely safe, but a much more viable option than running as root... Possibly acceptable on, say, a home server

Comment: @Pekka - Either way, PHP is able to halt the system (via SUID bit or a cron job). I was illustrating that in this particular case, shutdown doesn't do anything other than ... shut down. You would _not_ want to do this with a tool like traceroute or ping. Still, as noted - if the OP's system gets p0wned - the attacker can shut down the system either way. Using setuid in this case is no more / less dangerous than using a drop file that cron picks up. However, it reduces complexity and has the bonus of running immediately.

Comment: Yet this solution did not work as expected. I copied (`sudo cp /sbin/shutdown /var/www`) the shutdown script to an accessible location, but still get the error `shutdown: Need to be root` when I try to run it from a PHP script: `echo shell_exec('/var/www/shutdown now');`

Comment: @Honoki Is your `/sbin/shutdown` a compiled executable or shell script? Did you set the suid bit? `sudo chmod 4755 /var/www/shutdown`? I'd put it _out_ of the document root, but somewhere PHP is able to find and run it.

Comment: @TimPost I did set the suid bit. The `/sbin/shutdown` looks ilke a compiled executable. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 3):

What about giving the user, that runs apache, the permission to run shutdown with sudo rights?

Open the sudoers file with

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the line

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown
```

(*www-data* should be the user that runs apache. You can check this with `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and assuming the shutdown binary is in */sbin*)

Save with ctrl-O

Now this should work in php:

```
system("sudo shutdown 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running exec like this

```
exec( 'shutdown -h now', $output, $return_val );

print_r( $output );
echo "\n";
echo 'Error: '. $return_val ."\n";
```

And look at the errors, I just tried running a php script with the root user and it worked on my machine.

If this does not work, consider having a cronjob running under root privileges that checks periodically if it should run shutdown on the macine.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I decide to go with an easy one:
exec("ssh root@localhost reboot")
Just make sure you have your user id ('user's'/.ssh/rsa_id.pub) on /root/.ssh