# How to suspend/restart Linux Ubuntu from PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, restart

I have a problem. I want to restart ubuntu with php code but I can not. I have tried all of codes from the internet like

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/sbin/reboot");
exec("/usr/sbin/reboot");
system("/usr/sbin/reboot");
?>
```

and

```
<?php
shell_exec("shutdown -r");
exec("shutdown -r");
system("shutdown -r");
?>
```

But all of them do nothing. Please help me. I need this code.

Answer (score 2):

If the PHP code is being executed by the webserver, it is running under the user "www-data" in ubuntu.

Probably www-data has no right to shutdown, which is a sane default.

You can give www-data sudo rights to shutdown without providing a password and call reboot using sudo.

Take a good look at `man sudoers` and be sure to understand the security implications before editing the sudo config: this will effectively give any PHP script the right to shutdown the server (untested).

```
# /etc/sudoers (edit using the visudo command)

Cmnd_Alias     SHUTDOWN = /usr/sbin/shutdown
Cmnd_Alias     HALT = /usr/sbin/halt
Cmnd_Alias     REBOOT = /usr/sbin/reboot

Host_Alias     LOCALHOST = 127.0.0.1

www-data       LOCALHOST = NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN, HALT, REBOOT
```

In PHP you can use:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/reboot");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to giving root access to the PHP user

Check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226760/2708670

Comment: i saw your link . but i do not understand exactly .

Comment: I know about this is dangerous but I need this code for exercise